# Publishing Asp.Net Core MVC from VS 2015 to Azure VM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have jumped through a lot of hoops fixing minor things just to get to this point and I have run out of leads. I have an ASP.Net CORE MVC application. It builds just fine locally and runs great but now I am trying to move it to an Azure VM so I can have users do some basic testing as well. Basically I am at the point where I created the publish profile and upon trying to do a publish I no longer get errors but the destination folder is empty save for a placeholder file I have. I am pasting in the Build log below for reference:

```
Configuring project completed successfully
publish: Published to C:\Users\hyro7\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\UI34
Published 1/1 projects successfully
Web App was published successfully (removed for client privacy)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I went to the temp location and do see files have been copied there and even after this process concludes the web browser opens and takes me to the destination as normal. Start to finish, I get no errors but no files are actually copied to the VM.

I know my VM settings are correct because I do have another application publishing to that server and that works just fine, the only difference is that application is just MVC 5.

Please let me know if you need to see any other information or if there is a simple solution to this that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Wich OS do you have on your virtual machine....did you try uploading your project to github and clone it on your VM?

Comment: the VM is running Windows Server 2016. I've never tried uploading something to github, do you think something is wrong with using visual studio to do the publishing?

Comment: Just wanted to also add I created a new Web App in Azure and made a publish profile for it. Doing a publish that way worked just fine so now I'm really stumped as to why the files aren't copying to the VM but they do work for the web app.